Cast this to generic type without tricking compiler
Consider this simplified class hierarchy:
public interface IProcessor
{
  Task<TProcessor> Run<TProcessor>() where TProcessor : IProcessor;
}


public abstract class Processor : IProcessor
{

  public async Task<TProcessor> Run<TProcessor>() where TProcessor : IProcessor
  {
    await DoWork();
    return (TProcessor)(object)this;  // works, but yuck
    //return (TProcessor)this;        // error: "Cannot convert type 'Processor' to 'TProcessor'"
  }

  protected abstract Task DoWork();

}


public sealed class FooProcessor : Processor
{
  protected override Task DoWork() => Task.CompletedTask;
}

The (TProcessor)(object)this trick works, but is an ugly compiler hack.
Can I modify this code to rely on compile-time checks instead?

The error message is entirely correct and you should not be trying to suppress it.  TProcessor can be *any type implementing IProcessor, and this will not necessarily be that type.  Your code is asking the caller to supply a type, and then just throwing a runtime exception if they didn't happen to guess the one type  you actually wanted.  Don't do that.

@Servy Thanks. I definitely don't want to suppress the error. So there's no way to refactor this? (Other than a redesign, which I'd like to avoid unless necessary.)

I don't know if your example is too simple but there doesn't seem to be a reason to use generics here at all. There's also no guarantee that Processor will be an appropriate type for TProcessor either.

@phuzi Thanks. Yes it's a simplistic example (of a very complex hierarchy). I will have to redesign I guess.

would a variable do the job? Like this:
IProcessor me = this;
return (TProcessor)me;
or would you consider this ugly aswell?

@Azzarrel Thanks. Though that gives the same error as above. The compiler is quite smart. As mentioned above, the error message indicates that it's really a bad idea to circumvent the type system (which I don't want to do).

I guess there is a reason we just don't have Task

A run time error is possible if you have another class inheriting from Processor, say BarProcessor. Then BarProcessor p = new FooProcessor().Run<BarProcessor>(); will compile, but will fail at run time.
C# does not support a "self" type like this (see for example https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/5413 ), but the code can be improved by moving the type parameter from the method to the type. This restricts the potential for mistakes to the class implementations and reduces the need to specify type parameters at the call site.
For example:
public interface IProcessor<TProcessor> where TProcessor : IProcessor<TProcessor>
{
    Task<TProcessor> Run();
}

public abstract class Processor<TProcessor> : IProcessor<TProcessor>
    where TProcessor : Processor<TProcessor>
{
    public async Task<TProcessor> Run()
    {
      await DoWork();
      return (TProcessor)this;
    }

    protected abstract Task DoWork();
}

public sealed class FooProcessor : Processor<FooProcessor>
{
    protected override Task DoWork() => Task.CompletedTask;
}

public sealed class BarProcessor : Processor<BarProcessor>
{
    protected override Task DoWork() => Task.CompletedTask;
}

Now callers of Run cannot specify a wrong type parameter (since there isn't any), but FooProcessor can still erroneously inherit from Processor<BarProcessor>. Also, the interface IProcessor<TProcessor> is now clearly only useful as a constraint (where T: IProcessor<T>), not as a type.
Note that FooProcessor and BarProcessor are sealed. Allowing inheritance from a Processor<TProcessor> subclass will require that subclass to be generic, like public abstract class SpecialProcessor<TProcessor> : Processor<TProcessor> where TProcessor : SpecialProcessor<TProcessor>.

Thanks! Funnily enough this was the original design but I was trying to "simplify it" without success. I guess it was like that for a reason! :-)

That self constraint proposal would be useful. Nice find, and thanks again!
